# Asp.net c# Gauge

Tags: asp.net

I want to make a gauge in asp.net using c# for slide show.
Can anybody help me how I make a gauge? I have no idea about it.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a very (very) old post, but give it a try: [slider Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531450.aspx), or a direct [IE>=5 link here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/behaviors/library/slider/slider.htm)

**EDIT**: You can also use some commercial componentes, like Telerik. See their [ASP.NET Slider Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/slider/examples/slideshow/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial gauge controls available. For example, look at http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGaugesDemos/